# How to programatically map dropdownList Controls to Label Controls in ASP.NEt C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a survey program in ASP.NET C# which I'm writing. I have 56 different dropdownList controls to be mapped to 56 label controls. I don't want tomap it through the conventionaly way list this:

```
    lblSummary1.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
    lblSummary2.Text = DropDownList2.SelectedValue;
    lblSummary3.Text = DropDownList3.SelectedValue;
    .
    .
    lblSummary56.Text = DropDownList56.SelectedValue;
```

So I decided to write it programmatically like this:

```
    // Map all the dropDown Selected Data to the their Various Labels
    string mylbl = "lblSummary";
    string myddl = "DropDownList";
    int counter;
    int totalAnswers = 57;
    for (counter = 1; counter < totalAnswers; counter++ )
    {
        mylbl += counter.ToString() + "." + "Text;<br/>";
        myddl += counter.ToString() + "." + "Text;<br/>";
        mylbl = myddl;
    }
```

In order to see the output, I mapped the answers to a label like below:

```
    lblSummary57.Text = myddl;
```

This is result I got was

```
    DropDownList1.Text;
    2.Text;
    3.Text;
    4.Text;
    5.Text;
    6.Text;
    7.Text;
    8.Text;
    .
    .
    .
    56.Text;
```

Please kinly help meout a I'm new to ASP.NET

Thank You.

Comment: I'ts not clear what your question is, what is the expected result (what do you want)?

Comment: The expcted result should be: 
label1.Text = dropDownList1.SelectedValue;
label2.Text = dropDownList2.SelectedValue;

This labels are then displayed on a summary page with whatever is selected from the dropDownList controls.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31hxzsdw.aspx) method to get the label or dropdown by their id dynamically. You can use container instead of Page and that would be fast.

```
Page.FindControl("DropDownList" + i);
```

You can go through dropdowns and lables with something like this,

```
for (counter = 1; counter < totalAnswers; counter++ )
{
   DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList ) Page.FindControl("DropDownList" + counter);
   Label lblSummary = (Label ) Page.FindControl("lblSummary" + counter); 
   lblSummary.Text = ddl .SelectedValue;
}
```

Comment: Hi Adil...Is I supposed to be the counter increment?

Comment: I got the NullReferenceException on the page. How do I fix this?

Comment: You need to use counter instead of i, also change lblSummary1 to lblSummary as @tariq pointed.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (counter = 1; counter < totalAnswers; counter++ )
{
    mylbl = "lblSummary" + counter.ToString() + "." + "Text";
    myddl = "DropDownList" + counter.ToString() + "." + "SelectedValue";
    mylbl = myddl;
}
```

Comment: I have tried his and it doesn't work.

Below is my modified code which is not different from yours.

        int counter;
        int totalAnswers = 57;
        for (counter = 1; counter < totalAnswers; counter++ )
        {
           string mylbl = "lblSummary" + counter.ToString() + "." + "Text";
           string myddl = "DropDownList" + counter.ToString() + "." + "Text";
           mylbl = myddl;
        }